# How many attestations d'accueil (Welcome letter) for a family of two?

Tags: visa, france

I recently received an *attestation d'accueil* from my local City Hall. This is to invite my mother and father from India to France for a short visit of less than 90 days.

I have received ONE *attestation d'accueil* (ADA) in which both my parents' details have been mentioned. The ADA looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223318/cerfa-10798-03.pdf) (sample pdf).

I noticed only today that a separate interview needs to be scheduled for each family member as per [VFS-France-India](http://www.vfs-france.co.in/FAQ.html)

> Q:13- We are a family of three. How many appointments do I schedule?
>
> One appointment per person has to be scheduled.

Does this mean that I need to provide my mother and father separate ADAs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The law (technically a *réglement*, not a *loi* but it's “the law” in English all the same) clearly specifies that your parents can be on the same *attestation*. From the *[Code de l'entrée et du séjour des étrangers et du droit d'asile](http://www.legifrance.org/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=3CD04E4C4428D658B60D50E916ACE340.tpdjo14v_2?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006335500&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158&dateTexte=20111108)*:

> Article R211-15
>
> Le conjoint et les enfants mineurs de dix-huit ans de l'étranger accueilli peuvent figurer sur l'attestation d'accueil souscrite à son profit.

This implies that you shouldn't need to pay for another *attestation* and obviously the form is also designed for that. But I have no idea how VFS handles this in practice. Hopefully, providing copies and explaining the situation will be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The form does make allowance for a spouse. I assume that the information you have here is from [**legifrance**](http://www.legifrance.org/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=3CD04E4C4428D658B60D50E916ACE340.tpdjo14v_2?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006335500&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158&dateTexte=20111108)?

Comment: @drN Yes, I added your link to my answer, thanks! Technically, I should have specified it's an article from the CESEDA. In France, this unambiguously identifies a particular piece of legislation, which can be found on legifrance but also elsewhere.